# How to solve negative Power in Lisp

Tags: math, lisp

Today, we used LISP for the first time in our Artificial Intelligence class. Well, the LISP compiler was not readily available,  so we dry run every code.

I am currently having a problem with the `POWER` function when it is raised to a negative number. I asked the lecturer and he said I should do that myself and boasted he will set it in the exam coming up on Wednesday. I searched online, I found some tutorials saying it will produce an error and you should output a customized error message, just then I remembered Stackoverflow.

Here is a sample program I did already but the power is a positive integer.

```
(DE POWER (M N)
   (COND ((ZEROP N) 1)
    (T (TIMES M (POWER M (SUB 1 N)))))
```

Example

> M = 4, N = 3

```
(POWER 4 3)
 (TIMES 4 (POWER 4 2))
 (TIMES 4 (TIMES 4 (POWER 4 1)))
 (TIMES 4(TIMES 4(TIMES 4 ( POWER 4 0))))
(TIMES 4(TIMES 4 (TIMES 4 1)))
 (TIMES 4 (TIMES 4 4))
  (TIMES 4 16)
       64
```

Now, how can solve the following using a LISP program?

> M = 4, N = -3

Are there any function to tackle negative powers in LISP or is there a systematic step to solve this?

Comment: What dialect of Lisp is that? `DE` is not Common Lisp syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Really? I asked him what's `DE`, he said it means `DEFINITION`. More Like defining a procedure

Comment: High school math: `x ** -y` is `1 / (x ** y)`

Comment: In Common Lisp it's `DEFUN` (for define function). What dialect of Lisp is this?

Comment: Can't tell cause he just wrote LISP that day and I bet sure he does not  have an idea about writing programs. But must be an old version cause the textbook he was using is quite old (he won't even tell us the name of the textbook).

Comment: Looks like PicoLisp.

Comment: Just found out that it is Vlisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M^(-N) = 1 / (M^N).  So you can check for negative N and return 1 / M^(-N).

```
(DE POWER (M N)
   (COND ((ZEROP N) 1)
   ((< N 0) (/ 1 (POWER M (- 0 N))))
   (T (TIMES M (POWER M (SUB 1 N)))))
```